# react-pdf: use PDFDownloadLink asynchronously without blocking the rest of the application

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I'm using `PDFDownloadLink` from the `react-pdf` package to generate a PDF on the fly in my application and allow the user to download a report based on data being passed to the component that generates the PDF document. However, there are more than 400 pages that need to be rendered in this PDF, and this operation blocks the main thread for a few seconds. Is there any way to make this operation asynchronous, so the rest of the application will continue to function while the PDF is being generated? Also I would like to be able to cache the results, since the data being passed to the component can come from about 8 different arrays of data, which don't change very much, so switching between these arrays I would rather not to have to render the PDF all over again if the PDF for that given array has already been generated once before... I'm guessing the blob data needs to be stored somewhere, perhaps localStorage?

```js
import { Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet, PDFDownloadLink } from '@react-pdf/renderer'
const App = () => {
    const condition = "firstCondition";
    const filteredRowData = rowData.filter(a => a.condition = condition);
    return (
            <PDFDownloadLink
                document={<PDF_REPORT_Document rowData={filteredRowData} />}
                fileName={"PDF_REPORT.pdf"}
                style={{color:'white'}}
                >{({ blob, url, loading, error }) =>
                    loading ? "Report loading..." : "Report ready to download"
                }</PDFDownloadLink>
    );
}

const PDF_REPORT_Document = (props) => {
    const { rowData } = props;
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        page: {
          flexDirection: 'column',
          backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4'
        },
        section: {
          margin: 10,
          padding: 10,
          flexGrow: 1
        }
    });

    return(
        <Document>
        {rowData.map((row,index) => 
            <Page size="A4" style={styles.page} key={index}>
                <View style={styles.section}>
                    <Text>Name: {row.FULLNAME}</Text>
                </View>
            </Page>
        )}
        </Document>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this in an [issue on github](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/736) which addresses this exact problem:

> **Is your feature request related to a problem? Please describe.**
> It is an improvement. At the moment, if you use 'PDFDownloadLink' the PDF is being generated as the component loads.
>
> **Describe the solution you'd like**
> It is not mandatory, but having multiple heavy PDFs ready to be downloaded wouldn't be the best approach since not every user will need it.
>
> **Describe alternatives you've considered**
> I've used `pdf()` function to generate the blob and `file-saver` lib to download it:
>
> ```
> import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
> import { pdf } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
> import PdfDocument from '../PdfDocument';
>
> const generatePdfDocument = async (documentData,fileName) => {
>         const blob = await pdf((
>             <PdfDocument
>                 title='My PDF'
>                 pdfDocumentData={documentData}
>             />
>         )).toBlob();
>         saveAs(blob, fileName);
> };
>
> export default generatePdfDocument;
> ```

Comment: It takes 22 seconds to generate the blob on IE for simple content while on chrome it takes merely 3 seconds. @JohnRDOrazio can you help me with this?

Comment: you might want to check for issues or open a new issue on the github repo linked in the answer. I'm afraid I'm not the one that can help you.

Comment: what is fileName? @JohnRDOrazio

Comment: @Derek it is a variable that represents any fileName you would like to give to the final PDF. If you look at the example on the github issue I linked to, this is the exact code offered; however to make it clearer now I have updated the example code with `fileName` as a second parameter you can pass into the function

Comment: what is <PdfDocument /> from the code ?

Comment: @Siri <PdfDocument /> is the Document component.

Comment: For example:
<Document>
    <Page size="A4" >
          <View >
               <Text>Your Text</Text>
          </View>
    </Page>
 </Document>